# Convert 0800 to 8.00 in ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I convert `0800` to `8.00 hrs` in ruby? I have been trying to split at index `2` and `join`, but am not able to do so.

Comment: Not sure what you want. If you convert `0830`, do you get `8.30` or `8.50`?

Comment: `0800` itself is a non-valid identifier. `"0800"` is valid.

Comment: @Amadan, I want it 8.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is always a `String` (and I think it has to be), you can do this:

```
input = "0800"
input.insert(2, ":")
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this.

Comment: This returns `"08:00"`, not `"8.00"`

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'time'    
Time.strptime("0800", "%H%M").strftime("%-H.%M hrs")
#  => "8.00 hrs"
Time.strptime("0830", "%H%M").strftime("%-H.%M hrs")
# => "8.30 hrs"
```

Comment: Use `strftime('%-H.%M hrs')` instead of appending `' hrs'`

Comment: @Stefan. much better now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
time = "0830"
sprintf("%.2f", time.to_f / 100)
# => 8.30
```